# In SSRS what is the difference between a Tablix filter or a query where clause

Tags: sql, reporting-services, filter, parameters, ssrs-tablix

You can filter with a SSRS parameter in the local dataset query or in the Tablix. Is there a time you would use one or the other?

Answer (score 3):

From my experience

I alway use `WHERE` clause more than Filter on Reporting Service because it's faster. Imagin you retrieve **all data** to report then filter again but if you use `WHERE` clause you select only data you want **only** it can reduce number of row and faster than use Filter on reporting service

Then I use Filter on Reporting service some time for example show Employee data in two Tablix and split `TableA` for employee who are male and `TableB` for employee who are female

this case I retrieve all employee at once into single Dataset then use Tablix Filter for filter gender of employee again.